# Definitions of the average speed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity

> We have the following definitions of average speed:
>
> (a) the average of the values of the instantaneous speed over a time interval.
>
> (b) the magnitude of the average velocity.
>
> Are these definitions equivalent? Explain your conclusion with two examples.

Well as this site demands that anyone who try to give such question to begin with his try, my answer is:

No they are not equivalent, the first is the average of all velocities of the moving object, the second is half the value of the difference between the highest and the lowest velocities.

I will give the following example
First: A body moving in constant high velocity for a long period, and then slowed down very quickly until stop.

- If we use the first definition, then the average speed is very close to the magnitude of the maximum velocity.
- If we use the second definition, then the average speed is half the magnitude of the maximum speed.

Comment: "half the value of the difference between the highest and the lowest velocities"? hmm.. this isn't equivalent to any of the definitions you wrote. How did you get this?

Comment: Sorry I am not an English native speaker, sometimes things get hard...This is the best understanding I could reach... If you can hep me please do.

Comment: This is not related to English. Lets write mathematically the 3 definitions you introduced:$$ $$ 

half the value of the difference between the highest and the lowest velocities =$$\frac{v_{max}-v_{min}}{2}$$ 

the magnitude of the average velocity = $$\left |\frac{\Delta \vec{r}}{\Delta t}\right |=\left |\frac{1}{\Delta t} \int \vec{v}dt \right | $$ 

the average of the values of the instantaneous speed over a time interval = 
$$ \frac{1}{\Delta t} \int |\vec{v}| dt  $$

Comment: I understand that the two definitions of the average speed, which are presented in the question are equivalent. (because the last two formulas you have included in your question are equivalent).

Comment: Are they equivalent? Try taking it to the discrete case: is $|a+b|$ always equal to $|a|+|b|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two definitions are *not* equivalent, because (b) says “the magnitude of the average velocity”. For a particle in periodic motion (such as uniform circular motion or simple harmonic motion) the average velocity over one period is zero, so the magnitude of the average velocity over one period is also zero - but average speed over one period is obviously not zero.

If definition (b) said “the average magnitude of the velocity” then the definitions would be equivalent, since speed is the magnitude of velocity.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether I understood your question properly. But **average speed** is **the total distance divided by the total time for the journey**.$$\text{average speed}=\frac{\text{total distance}}{\text{total time}}$$ If the rate of change of speed is constant it is equal to $$\frac{v_{\text{final}}+v_{\text{initial}}}{2}$$ 
(The rate of change of speed is corresponding to the *acceleration* if you are talking about *velocity*)

Comment: That's average velocity

Comment: @OfekGillon Wouldn't average velocity be total *displacement*/total time? I think ACB's answer is correct.

Comment: @Jonas, I agree that total displacement over total time is average velocity, But I'm not sure if distance isn't a synonym for displacement ($\int \vec{dr}$). If distance is equal to $\int |\vec{dr}|$, then yes, he is right